# Problemas com sql no access, tipos de dados incompatíveis

Tags: sql, microsoft-access

Imagem do teste/erro:

[image: Erro de consulta ao Access]

Pretendo apenas buscar os dados entre uma data e outra, usando:

```
SELECT * FROM tblTRAZA
WHERE FECMOV >= '2013-01-03'
AND FECMOV <= '2013-01-09';
```

Mas já tentei outros formatos de data para consulta como `yyyy/mm/dd`, tentei usar apenas a data sem às horas, e como na imagem, tentei usar uma data específica que já tinha cadastrada, porém esse erro me persegue. É possível que tenha que alterar a estrutura da data da tabela?

Comment: Quebrei a cabeça um pouco e consegui descobrir o formato de data usado pelo access aqui, e ficou assim:

SELECT *
FROM tblTRAZA
WHERE (((tblTRAZA.FECMOV)>=#5/30/2014 00:00:00#)
AND ((tblTRAZA.FECMOV)<=#5/31/2014 23:59:59#))
ORDER BY FECMOV;

Comment: que bom que conseguiu. Poste como uma resposta e marque ela como resolvida para que possa ajudar futuros visitantes!

Answer (score 1):

Quebrei a cabeça um pouco e consegui descobrir o formato de data usado pelo access no caso desse banco, e ficou assim:

> SELECT *
>       FROM tblTRAZA
>       WHERE (tblTRAZA.FECMOV BETWEEN **#5/20/2014 00:00:00#** And **#5/31/2014 23:59:59#**)

Os campos de datas são entendidos pelo sql do access quando se coloca a data completa entre '#' (jogo da velha kkk), e o formato de data foi colocado como `MM/DD/YYYY`.

OBS: o banco está em MDB (formato ACCESS 2002)